# How to read $\cup_{j,k=1}^{\infty} I_{k,j}$, which is $\cup_{j=1}^{\infty} \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_{k,j}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

How to read $\cup_{j,k=1}^{\infty} I_{k,j}$, which is $\cup_{j=1}^{\infty} \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_{k,j}$?

They are the same set based on my notes, but I don't understand how to read the former syntax.

Comment: @metamorphy Yes, but I don't get how to read the former syntax.

Comment: $\bigcup_{j,k=1}^\infty I_{k,j}$ is the union of $I_{k,j}$ over all pairs of positive integers $(k,j)$. This is the same as the other notation, but I prefer to write $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_{k,j}$ because it is more clear.